# Alpine INBOX contains 0 messages

Tags: email, imap, alpine-linux

I configured two collection lists in Alpine. In M S L.
I entered a nickname and then a server in the following way:

`mail.server:993/ssl/user=username`

After entering the password all mails are displayed in INBOX including all subfolders. They can be edited, etc.
After a while the INBOX is empty. Only the INBOX. All subfolders still work. The only thing that works is deleting and reading the collection list. Restarting Alpine doesn't work.

This happens to both collection lists but not at the same time.

Does anybody have an idea what this can be?

Thanks in advance,
Stefan

Comment: Does this only happen when the inbox has too many messages?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem, but I am only using one collection list. My inbox was always empty in Alpine although I knew that wasn't true and there were emails in there. I was able to get my inbox in Alpine back again by editing the ~/.pinerc file and searching for "inbox-path" and setting it as follows:

inbox-path={imap.gmail.com:993/ssl/user=}Inbox

with  as your actual gmail email address. Once I did that and restarted Alpine, it was able to retrieve messages. I don't know how this will work with two gmail accounts in Alpine. Maybe roles (S R R)?

Comment: I have several collections configured, and I experienced the same problem with the top-most collection only. Adding the correct inbox-path for that collection seems to have solved the problem.